# Android - Progressive download over HTTPS

Tags: android, video, https, progressive-download

I am using following code to play a video from SDCard and HTTP links

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(**videoUrl**));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

if the videoUrl is a HTTP then video player opens immediately and video starts playing through progressive download.

But if the videoUrl is a HTTPS url, then android downloads the entire video file, and then I have to click the file in "downloads" list to play the file.

I found that android media player doesn't support HTTPS (http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/7e7003b845c3fb98),

so does anyone know how to progressively download HTTPS videos?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

> Note: HTTPS is not supported before Android 3.1.

Therefore, You should try again.